# Why does inConfig(conf)(settings) not pick some settings?

Tags: sbt

I thought that `inConfig(conf)(settings)` would copy all settings into the given configuration. But this doesn't seem to do what I would expect.

Given a configuration:

```
lazy val Monkjack: Configuration = config("monkjack")
```

Then I do:

```
inConfig(Monkjack)(Defaults.compileSettings)
```

So I can do compile as I would expect:

```
sbt clean monkjack:compile
[info] Compiling 17 Scala sources to ...
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed 01-Sep-2014 09:40:41
```

So now I want to adjust the scalac options when using this new config (the actual options are irrevlant, this one is just useful because it has verbose output so its easy to see if its being used or not):

```
scalacOptions in Monkjack := Seq("-Yshow-syms")
```

When I `monjack:compile`, I don't see this option being triggered. It's like the above line wasn't added. But if I also add in the following lines it works!

```
sources in Monkjack := (sources in Compile).value
sourceDirectory in Monkjack := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value,
```

So why do I need the final two lines and what is `inConfig` actually doing if its not doing what I expect. As an additional oddity, when I do the above, although it works, I get two compile phases, one going to `target/classes` and one going to `target/monkjack-classes`.

Edit (inspect without the sources/sourceDirectory settings)

```
> inspect tree monkjack:compile
[info] monkjack:compile = Task[sbt.inc.Analysis]
[info]   +-monkjack:compile::compileInputs = Task[sbt.Compiler$Inputs]
[info]   | +-*:compilers = Task[sbt.Compiler$Compilers]
[info]   | +-monkjack:sources = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
[info]   | +-*/*:maxErrors = 100
[info]   | +-monkjack:incCompileSetup = Task[sbt.Compiler$IncSetup]
[info]   | +-monkjack:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | | +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-*/*:sourcePositionMappers = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Function1[xsbti.Position, scala.Option[xsbti.Position]]]]
[info]   | +-monkjack:dependencyClasspath = Task[scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]]
[info]   | +-monkjack:classDirectory = target/scala-2.11/monkjack-classes
[info]   | +-monkjack:scalacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   | +-*:javacOptions = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]]
[info]   | +-*/*:compileOrder = Mixed
[info]   | 
[info]   +-monkjack:compile::streams = Task[sbt.std.TaskStreams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]     +-*/*:streamsManager = Task[sbt.std.Streams[sbt.Init$ScopedKey[_ <: Any]]]
[info]
```

Comment: Can you do `show monkjack:scalacOptions`?

Comment: Do you see `monkjack:scalacOptions` listed in `inspect tree monkjack:compile`?

Comment: > show monkjack:scalacOptions
[info] List(-Yshow-syms)

Comment: Added inspect output to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** No sources for a new configuration means no compilation and hence no use of `scalacOptions`.

From [When to define your own configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#When+to+define+your+own+configuration):

> If your plugin introduces either a new set of source code or its own library dependencies, only then you want your own configuration.

`inConfig` does the (re)mapping only so all the keys are initialised for a given scope - in this case the `monkjack` configuration.

In other words, `inConfig` computes values for the settings in a new scope.

The settings of much influence here are `sourceDirectory` and `sourceManaged` that are set in `sourceConfigPaths` (in [Defaults.sourceConfigPaths](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L177-L178)) as follows:

```
lazy val sourceConfigPaths = Seq(
  sourceDirectory <<= configSrcSub(sourceDirectory),
  sourceManaged <<= configSrcSub(sourceManaged),
  ...
)
```

`configSrcSub` [gives the answer](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L38) (reformatted slightly to ease reading):

```
def configSrcSub(key: SettingKey[File]): Initialize[File] =
  (key in ThisScope.copy(config = Global), configuration) { (src, conf) => 
    src / nameForSrc(conf.name)
  }
```

That leads to the answer that if you moved your sources to `src/monkjack/scala` that would work fine. That's described in [Scoping by configuration axis](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+configuration+axis):

> A configuration defines a flavor of build, potentially with its own classpath, sources, generated packages, etc. (...)
>   By default, all the keys associated with compiling, packaging, and running are scoped to a configuration and therefore may work differently in each configuration.

Comment: So I need a config that adjusts the monkjack:compile scope by adding in some extra scalacOptions. I guess I could adjust the compile scope itself and not introduce a new config.

Comment: That's the idea behind new configs - to change more than a couple of settings that could otherwise be changed using less complex means.

Comment: I need to do a lot more than my question indicates though :)

Comment: I want to allow people to have the plugin, but only activate it sometimes using the command line. Eg, sbt `something` compile or sbt something:compile. This is so people can have two jobs, one to activate the plugin, one without. That's why I don't think I can just do it by affecting compile directly.

Comment: Why don't you create the plugin with its own tasks?

Comment: Can a task do nothing other than make settings? Can I do like: monkjack := { source in Compile = .... }. I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: You can't. That's a command and needs reloading a project. What do you really want to achieve? Let's talk offline. Mail me.